# How do post IDs work in WordPress?

Tags: posts, mysql, id

So I have 2 blog posts so far and the first one has ID `8` and second one has ID `12`. How exactly does WordPress count those IDs? What if I want to change ID `8` and ID `12` to ID `1` and ID `2`? I have some knowledge about MySQL and I know that post IDs are related to the wp_posts table of the DataBase. How to edit the IDs? I have WordPress 3.9.2 and access to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the Post ID.

Wordpress uses serialized data, and id's have deep linking within the database.

Comment: But I have just 2 posts. It's almost a fresh install. I don't want to re-install it because my settings and posts will be lost. Isn't there any way to change just 2 post IDs?

Comment: Why do you want to change the post ID?

Comment: Well, jumping from 1 to 8 and then from 8 to 12 for sequential posts doesn't look good to me. And since I'm using this kind of custom permalinks: `example.com /archives/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/%post_id%/` the post id is shown in the URI.

Comment: Posts are not sequential.  Everything in wordpress is a post.  Every revision, virtually every action is a post, just a different post type.  Just title the post "post1" and use the permalink /%postname%/

Comment: It will be nearly impossible to keep the post IDs sequential for blog posts on your site as many other areas make use of the wp_posts table.  Media, custom post types, pages, etc... All of those will affect the current post_id in the wp_posts table.

Comment: Alright then, I guess I won't be changing it anytime soon. Thanks anyways.